# Replacing the contents of a TD based on certain conditions using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to accomplish the following:

I have a table that holds data that I need to edit/format:

```
<tr><td>Tools and Other: Hammers</td><tr>
<tr><td>Tools and Other: Wrenches</td><tr>
```

Based on conditions, I need to change the contents to the following:

```
<tr><td>Toolbox: Hammer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Toolkit: Wrench</td></tr>
```

How would I *simply* change the contents of these two TDs dynamically using jQuery?  Secondly - how would I remove just "Tools and Hammers" from every TD, if I decided to do it that way - like this:

```
<tr><td>Hammers</td></tr>
<tr><td>Wrenches</td></tr>
```

Comment: What are the conditions?

Comment: Remove `Tools and Hammers` or `Tools and Other`??

Answer (score 1):

You can change context of `TD`'s like this;

```
$('td').html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace('Tools and Other: ', '');
});
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/48u7a/)

Answer (score 0):

Given a table with the id `blah`, such as this:

```
<table id="blah">
    <tr><td>Tools and Other: Hammers</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tools and Other: Wrenches</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can do the replacement with code like this - http://jsfiddle.net/Khs7N/:

```
$("#blah tr td").each(function() {
    $(this).text(
        $(this).text().replace(
            /^Tools and Other/,
            "Toolbox"
        )
    );
});
```

The [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) at the beginning will find the element with the id `blah`, find all its `<tr>` children, and all those element's `<td>` children.  Then it will [execute the function for each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) of those elements.

The function simply grabs the text, calls [the JavaScript `string.replace` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) on it (using a regular expression) to correct the text, then sets the whole text of the element with the new string.

The [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matches "Tools and Other" only at the beginning of the string, using the `^` meta-character.